# strftime gets wrong date

Tags: php, date, strftime

I'm using strftime to display future date.

But while using

```
strftime('%a., %d. %B %Y',time()+60*60*24*4)
```

I'm getting Mo., 01. April 2013 instead of Su., 31.  March 2013 while using this today.

(Unix timestamp is 1364423120)

```
strftime('%a., %d. %B %Y',time()+60*60*24*3)
```

displays the correct Sa., 30. March 2013

What is wrong here with the last day of March?

Comment: what is your server timezone :)? Look closer at this function/setting: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz is there any timezone where March 31st is missing? I don't think so ;)

Comment: @gronostaj lousy Smarch weather...

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz: server timezone is set to Europe/Berlin, but as gronostaj pointed out as well that is not important (check the Sa., 30. March against the Mo., 01. April).

Comment: Bottom line: When adding days, do not forget that the length of the day is only 24 hours ON AVERAGE, with the occasional 23 or 25 hours for a day when daylight saving time is switched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The timestamp represents 23:25:20 local time.  As daylight savings time comes into effect on March 31th, adding 96 h will give 00:25:20 as local time, thus a date one day later than expected.  Using gmstrftime instead of strftime avoids this problem.

```
<?php

$timestamp = 1364423120;

echo strftime('%a., %d. %B %Y (%c %Z)', $timestamp)."\n";
echo strftime('%a., %d. %B %Y (%c %Z)', $timestamp +60*60*24*4)."\n";
echo gmstrftime('%a., %d. %B %Y (%c %Z)', $timestamp)."\n";
echo gmstrftime('%a., %d. %B %Y (%c %Z)', $timestamp +60*60*24*4)."\n";
```

gives

```
Wed., 27. March 2013 (Wed Mar 27 23:25:20 2013 CET)
Mon., 01. April 2013 (Mon Apr  1 00:25:20 2013 CEST)
Wed., 27. March 2013 (Wed Mar 27 22:25:20 2013 GMT)
Sun., 31. March 2013 (Sun Mar 31 22:25:20 2013 GMT)
```

Comment: D: Thats's it: it's the daylight savings time that brought this confusion. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: and thanks for suggesting gmstrftime(). Always sth. new to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Check your timezones.

Use the below code to see the time, timestamp, and timezone of the date produced by your code.

```
echo strftime('%s %H:%M:%S %z %Z %a., %d. %B %Y',time()+60*60*24*4);
//Output: 1364769859 15:44:19 -0700 PDT Sun., 31. March 2013
```

### edit:

If this is indeed a problem with DST in your area [North America's change was a couple weeks ago], and you're only interested in the 'day' part of the date then I would advise using [`date_add()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) instead of simple arithmetic since it will take into account DST changes, and other peculiarities of timekeeping.

Comment: He said tomorrow so I got confused.

Comment: @Starx I have a habit of not really reading the wordy bits of questions. It seems to work out better more often than not.

Comment: However, this basically is the same code as the OP has tried out. Does not answer the problem, except 'Check your timezones' which is really a comment.

Comment: @Starx: Thanks for mentioning date_add(). That it helpful as well.

Comment: Sorry, I meant @Sammitch: thanks for mentioning date_add(). It was a DST problem over here in europe/germany.

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual

> strftime — Format a local time/date according to locale settings

Its better if you specify a locale while you are using it, to avoid such problem.

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE");
strftime('%a., %d. %B %Y',time()+60*60*24*4)
```

Answer (score 1):

When I ran

```
echo strftime('%a., %d. %B %Y',time()+60*60*12*7)
```

I got

```
Sun., 31. March 2013
```

So this day truly exists :) I think it's connected to the daylight saving time change that happens on that day. And when you're using whole day (24 hours multiplying), you're skipping the timezone change.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. It was the daylight saving time. A quick fix for anyone reading this here is to use strtotime('12:00:00') instead of time().

Comment: @crnm glad I could help. When dealing with time, you have to pay great attention to timezones ALWAYS. Even now - when you know what was the problem - remember that your timezone is - by default - the one set on your server. You can also set different timezone for logged in users (if your app provides such thing)

Answer (score 0):

[Terje D.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1577260/terje-d) correctly mentions the confusion that you were getting with DST.
But I also wanted to mention a way to do it with DateTime, which in my personal opinion is easier to understand and use

```
$dt = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('UTC')); // creates a datetime object representing the current time in UTC
$dt->modify('+3 days'); // add 3 days to the datetime object
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n"; // This will give you the time in english independent of the locale settings on your server
echo strftime('%a., %d. %B %Y', $dt->getTimeStamp()); // this will give you the time in your locale, which as mentioned before, will include DST
```